# Filepond preview images horizontally

Tags: filepond

I am using Filepond version 4.7.3 and I know in version 4 they rolled out the ability to view items in grid view horizontally.

I have tried the following css:

`.filepond--item {
    width: calc(50% - .5em);
}`

but i still see images vertically

Comment: the above css is per their docs to make grid view work; although i don't see where they are changing their css to use grid

Comment: I figured out how to achieve this by commenting out the old css code for .filepond--item (  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0.25em;
  will-change: transform, opacity;)

Comment: I do have another question though - how do you attach images to the right; and also how do you keep the image size as for the largest image

Comment: I found the answer to this question too; FilePond.setOptions({
            itemInsertLocation: "after", 
            imagePreviewHeight: '50px'
        });